# How to add missing keywords to Pandoc language for syntax highlighting

Tags: html, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

I'm writing an ebook using Pandoc for a proprietary programming language, similar to SQL. I found out how to change the color by adding `-s --highlight-style haddock` when creating the book, but there are about 50 or so keywords that are missing. I noticed, reading through other posts, that you can change the color of the scheme, but I haven't found any way to actually create a new language with all the SQL keywords + my new ones or to just update the SQL language with the new keywords I need.

How can I create either a new language or update the SQL language to add my new keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc uses the syntax definitions of [Kate](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/highlight.html), the KDE editor. See the repo to see the [available syntax XML files](https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/tree/master/data/syntax).

To get the new keywords working, you'll need to modify the respective file and pass it to pandoc via the `--syntax-definition` option. Pass it as part of the `pandoc_args` field when using R Markdown.