# How to apply custom pandoc code-block syntax-highlighting to integer constants (e.g., 3L) in an rmarkdown::render()ed R script?

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

In applying a custom highlight theme (for HTML output) to R code blocks in a .R script, the pandoc syntax-highlighter fails to identify R integer constants (e.g., **3L**) and applies no highlighting.  String constants (e.g., **"howdy"**); unmarked integer, floating point, or scientific notation values (e.g., **3**, **17.22**, **5.3e27**); and logical constants (e.g., **TRUE**) are all parsed correctly and can thus be custom-formatted.

Here's a simple demo R script:

```
#' ---
#' title:  inttest.R
#' author: ""
#' date: ""
#' output: 
#'   html_document:
#'     highlight: pygments
#' ---
#' 
#' ## a heading
#'
data.dir <- "./Data/"  # comment comment(yes)
hortense <- 13 + 4     ## documentation
clarence <- TRUE
beverley <- 3L
maryanne <- c( g6 = 15.5, g7 = 534.333, g8 = NA )

if ( hortense > 16 ) { "YO" } else { "NOYO" }
ifelse( clarence, 1.23e5, -17 )

#' ## END ##
```

Using rmarkdown::render() with this script as input (and no other arguments specified) yields an HTML file in which all of the R code is appropriately highlighted, except for **3L**: The individual R code components are marked with appropriate  classes and formatting is applied on a class-by-class basis (from the specified custom highlight theme); but integer constants are not placed within a  class at all.

Replacing **pygments** in the YAML header with other built-in pandoc highlighting options, or with a custom .theme file, yields the same results.

On the other hand, if no highlight option is specified in the YAML header (**output: html_document** replaces the **output:** line and the following two), pandoc appears to use an entirely different syntax highlighter for code blocks ("highlightjs", perhaps, based on the R console's reported call to pandoc?):  All numeric constants (integers, fp, decimal, etc.) are tagged as  class "hljs-number" and highlighted correspondingly.  However, this highlighter appears not to tag a variety of other classes (e.g., function names), so it doesn't solve the general problem.

Note also that while the example here uses html_document as the output format, I'd actually like to use html_vignette (file sizes are <50KB, vs >500KB w/html_document); but html_vignette yields the same original problem, whether or not a highlight option is specified.

The underlying problem (bug, omission?) presumably lies in the code parser(s) for R syntax w/in pandoc, but I have no idea how to mess with that -- or whether that's even possible in pandoc when installed within R Studio (for MacOS), which is what I'm using (latest versions of R, RStudio, MacOS).  Based on this, the relevant R highlighter specification *might* be [this](https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/blob/b92403f8103390a68b85aacf5a3a0b9479959da4/data/syntax/r.xml), and there's a version of that file in my macOS RStudio installation at:  /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/share/pandoc/syntax-definitions/r.xml.

Solutions would include a workaround for the problem, or instructions on how to replace the existing pandoc code parser specification file(s?) for R with an improved version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging through SO and the Pandoc, KDE syntax-highlighting, and rmarkdown documentation, I came up with the following solution:

1. Edited a copy of the latest r.xml syntax-highlighting definition file packaged with Pandoc (from [here](https://kate-editor.org/syntax/); [file format documentation](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/kate/katepart/highlight.html)), to detect the marked integer type:  I added a **RegExpr** rule, just before the **Float** and **Int** rules in the **CommonRules** context, to find and label marked integers as "MarkedInt"; and I added an **ItemData** spec for the MarkedInt attribute to assign the "dsDataType" style.
2. Pandoc syntax-highlighting definition files are apparently compiled in (at least for Pandoc in RStudio for macOS), so for Pandoc to use the edited version, Pandoc needs to be called with its "--syntax-definition" option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70486118/21504362) & [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--syntax-definition)). B/c I'm calling pandoc indirectly by way of rmarkdown::render() with an R script as input, I [added the pandoc option to the R script's YAML header](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#pandoc-arguments):

   ```
    #' output: 
    #'   html_vignette:
    #'     highlight: <custom.theme>
    #'     pandoc_args: [ 
    #'       "--syntax-definition", "<custom.xml>"
    #'     ]
   ```

   This works with either html_vignette or html_document, with     <custom.xml> replaced by the edited syntax-definition xml file path, and with <custom.theme> replaced by a syntax-highlighting .theme file path (the latter assigns the desired formatting to the DataType default style -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47876166/21504362) and [here](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kate/katepart/color-themes.html)).

Comment: Excellent summary.  I too had trouble with something similar in Quarto and also found this blog post helpful:  https://hamel.dev/notes/quarto/highlighting.html